# Why do we have many teachings from Hillel and Shammai, but very few of earlier zugot?

Tags: history, historical-figures, mesorah-tradition, oral-torah, halachic-development

We venerate our previous generations, and have a principle of *yeridat hadorot*. Therefore *I would imagine* that the Torah of Samaya and Avtalyon, for example, would be pure gold for us, and threaded throughout Mishna and Shas to an even larger degree than the Torah of Hillel and Shammai. Yet it is not, we have only a handful of halachot in their name, and they hardly appear anywhere in any Talmudic-era works such as Midrash, Sifrei, Braitot and Tosefta.

**What are the exact historical or legal reasons** that this is actually not the case? For some, we haven't got a single halachic record or teaching, e.g. Mattai/Nittai of Arbela.

Contrast this to the point that we have, for example, a [huge amount of work from Philo](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/), who was alive at the time of Shamaya and Avtalyon, which demonstrates that the leading Rabbis of the time were writing extensively, and that it's certainly possible to have preserved such writings from that time.

Comment: How many halachot from hillel and shammai are there? Like 5?

Comment: @DoubleAA very interesting point and fair - I may be inappropriately lumping their "schools" with them themselves. I saw another question "why did Hillel and Shammai have schools, but not other zugot". Maybe this is a duplicate of that. What do you think?

Comment: Philo wasn't preserved by Jews. If early church fathers had thought Avtalyon's writings were interesting we'd probably still have them

Comment: The Church Father Epiphanius, who was born a Jew in a small village near Beit Guvrin (Eleutheropolis) wrote in his book Panarion that he was aware of four "repetitions", which scholars typically take to mean mishnayot compilations (as we know, Rebbi collected older compilations of mishnayot to form his mishna): That of Moshe (probably Sefer Devarim, AKA Mishneh Torah), that of Rabbi Akiva, That of Rabbi Yehuda (=Rebbi) and that of the Chashmonaim.

Comment: So we have here evidence for a mishnaic compilation from the time of the Chashmonaim (=Zugot) that was still known to some extent in Epiphanius's time (4th-5th cen.). Scholars connect this lost work to the few mentions of the "Beit Din shel Chashmonai" in the gemara.

Comment: @Harel13 I am deeply interested in this.

Comment: You can check out Y. N. Epstein's [מבואות לספרות התנאים, p. 17](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40976&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=) for more info. And also search in the document the word חשמונאי for more info on mishnayot from that era.

Comment: A. There were barely any arguments then, because the students were precise in their studies (Sanhedrin 88b)  B. It was forbidden to write down Torah Shebe’al Peh

Comment: @שלום thanks for filling in that important gap. I am surprised I didn't think of that. Is there any discussion you know of implying that they did write down divrei Torah of any kind?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.92a.8?lang=he&with=all

Comment: @Harel13 would consider a short write up of your comments as an answer very valuable, but of course up to you

Comment: Will do, whenever I can get around to it.

Comment: Perhaps the reason why is precisely _because_ of yeridas hadoros. Shmaya and Avtalyon were of such stature that there was no machlokes between them, and everything they knew was clearly Torah miSinai. Hence there was no Torah that was "theirs," and no need to know more than their names as part of the mesorah. ... That's purely conjecture on my part, though.

Comment: @Yehuda see N.T's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @RabbiKaii's request:

The reason that the teachings of the Zugot have been lost seems largely based on the reality of classic tannaitic and amoraic texts not including much of any of their teachings. Thus, while these works became more and more popular, other teachings were largely lost with time. Why these texts hardly included these teachings is a matter still heavily debated among academic scholars, though unless we uncover some lost works with clearer explanations (and I wouldn't lose hope for the possibility, every now and then we discover valuable lost works), or else wait for techiyat ha'metim, it seems like we'll never truly know for sure.

However, we do have a hint that a mishnaic compilation authored by personnel connected to the Chashmonaim or at least living in their time was still known circa the 4th-5th centuries. The Church Father Epiphanius, who was born a Jew in a small village near Beit Guvrin (Eleutheropolis), wrote in his book [Panarion, I, 15](https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/The_Panarion_of_Epiphanius_of_Salamis/IKyxt9kyys8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=aqiba&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover):

> "Scribes had four "repetitions." One  in the name of the prophet Moses, a second in that of their teacher called Aqiba or Bar Aqiba, another in the name of Addan or Annan, also called Judas, and another in the name of the sons of Hasmonaeus. Whatever customs they derive from these four traditions under the impression that they are wisdom - they are unwisdom mostly - are boasted of and praised, and celebrated and acclaimed as the teaching to be given first place."

According to Prof. Y. N. Epstein in his book Introductions to the Tannaitic Literature, p. 17, the "recitations" are mishnaic compilations (the word mishna comes from שנה, recite) and Epiphanius is speaking about four mishnaic compilations revered by the Jews: The first is Sefer Devarim, or Mishneh Torah, authored by Moshe. The second is by Rabbi Akiva, the third is by Rebbi (Rabbi Yehudah Ha'Nasi, the other two names are mistaken versions of the variants יודה and יודן) and the last one is from "the sons of the Chasmonaim".

Prof. Epstein mentions two relevant sources that may be related to the Mishnaic compilation from the time of the Chashmonaim:

Two mentions of a halachic ruling of a "beit din of Chashmonai" ([Avodah Zara 36b and Sanhedrin 82a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.36b.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Sanhedrin.82a.7&lang2=bi)), and a tradition brought in some versions of Halachot Gedolot which states that the elders of Beit Hillel and Beit Shammai wrote something called "the Scroll of the House of the Chashmonaim" ([link](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21295&st=&pgnum=793), and see n. 9).

From all of these sources, it seems that traditions of teachings and rulings from at least some of the Zugot or their contemporaries disappeared at least a couple of centuries after the creation of Rebbi's Mishna.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!! We are so enriched by this

Answer (score 6):

Because in those days there was very little to no machlokes:

> בראשונה לא היתה מחלוקת בישראל, אלא על הסמיכה בלבד
>
> In the beginning there was no disagreement in Israel, except regarding
> smicha (Yerushalmi Chagigah 2:2)

So no halachos had to be recorded in the names of individual sages.

Comment: Do you hav a source for this ?

Comment: Wondering if there were two factors in play for how frequent tannaim are mentioned per generation. One is the lack/presence of machlokes that you mentioned.  Another might be how much access Rabbi Yehuda Hanasi had to them. In this way there might have been a tendency that the ones in the generation of Rabbi Akiva's talmidim plus peers of Rabbi Akiva and the generation of Rabbi Akiva's rebbeim.

Comment: I made an informal list many years ago and there only ten tannaim that are mentioned by name in >= 50 mishnayos. In order they are Rabbis Yehuda (over 600), Yosi, Meir, Shimon (over 300 each), Eliezer, Akiva (high 200s each), Yehoshua (abt 140), Shimon ben Gamliel, Gamliel, Yishmael.  Bais Hillel/Shamai are each in just over 200 but Hillel and Shamai themselves each appear only in the mid-high teens.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt see Yerushalmi Chagigah 2:2: "בראשונה לא היתה מחלוקת בישראל, אלא על הסמיכה בלבד" and the Mishna described here is the one listing the zugot and their views regarding the smicha.