What books could be found in Rabbi Judah's library?
How did Rabbi Judah the Prince's bookcase look like?
As the most distinguished and rich Pharisee of his time, what books besides the Tanach, did he have in his library around 200 CE?
EDIT: As Rambam mentions in the preface to the MT, I understand that Rabbi had numerous handwritten notes from other Tannoyim, but were any of them (of the Oral tradition) compiled and distributed as a finished work?

While he redacted the Spoken Law into the Mishnah as we know it today, it sounds like there were various proto-Mishnaic materials circulating, as well as private notebooks.

Indeed I recently heard that he came upon a scene where many different Tanaaim were keeping their own notes in their own style, and he specifically went through all the styles in order to pick the best one for posterity. I believe he chose the style we have today because of how good it is for memorization. What else he had on his shelf is anyone's guess! Maybe he had some works by Shamaya and Shimon Ben Shetach? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136775/why-do-we-have-many-teachings-from-hillel-and-shammai-but-very-few-of-earlier-z

In addition to previous comments, Ben Sira was very popular, including among various sages, so possibly that. I would also hazard a guess that he had some works in Greek because he was in favor of learning Greek.

i have a theory that the reason why the mishna had to be written down was because people started reading books so we had to provide them with "kosher" reading material.  "heferu toratecha" is past tense, its already happening https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.63a.8-9. what were they reading? Homer (the odyssey) ספרי הומריס https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yadayim.4.6

The real answer is we have no idea.

https://www.academia.edu/39891633/Yaacov_Sussmann_Oral_Torah_Understood_Literally_The_Power_of_the_Tittle_of_the_Letter_Yod_in_Yaacov_Sussmann_and_David_Rosenthal_eds_Mehqerei_Talmud_Vol_III_Part_1_Talmudic_Studies_Dedicated_to_the_Memory_of_Professor_Ephraim_E_Urbach_Jerusalem_Magnes_2005_209_384_Hebrew_

There were several texts of Oral Law written prior to Mishnah. According to Iggeres Rav Sherira Gaon, (ch. 2) Rebbi mastered 13 approaches to the laws (see also Nedarim 41a).
When Rebbi had mastered 13 approaches to the laws, he taught r. Chiyya 7 of them. Rebbi took ill and forgot them. R. Chiyya restored the 7, but the other 6 were forgotten. There was a launderer who had heard when Rebbe used to recite them. R. Chiyya went and learned them from the launderer. [R. Chiyya] then went and repeated them before Rebbi. When Rebbi used to see the launderer, he would say to him: "You made me and r. Chiyya", According to some, he would say: "You made Chiyya, and Chiyya made me".
Very likely, this gemara alludes in part to the following texts. R. Yishmael and R. Shimon b. Yochai write two midrashei Mechilta, R. Chiya b. Abba wrote Sifra, also big portions of Sifre where written by different authors (described in Iggeres ch. 5). Tosefta of. R. Chiya and r. Oshaya were also studied by Rebbi - R. Yehudah ha Nasi (described in Iggeres ch. 4).

Thank you, why do you think we rely on the testimony of  Gaon some 800 years after R"Y? Why do we have no contemporary examples?

The Gaon describes a continuous recorded passage of our tradition with details of what each person did. Analysis of statements, present in the above mentioned texts, clearly points out to an earlier time than Mishna. The contemporary examples are also scattered in the Gemara and Yerushalmi, as I brought the example of Nedarim 41a. Rebbe learned from many people and their notes. Perhaps I will give another answer about it.

Right, I'm with you that numerous oral traditions existed before Rebbe's time, but it appears that before the Mishna none was published as a finished and named work. It's sort of an anachronism by the Goens and later generations to perceive oral traditions as "works". Frequently, we have tons of pseudepigraphy, where later Midrashim are ascribed to the Tannayim for credibility.

@AlBerko we do not have the original scrolls. We can only date based on people mentioned and language used. For example, the language of Zohar is medieval. The language of Seder Olam is from antiquity. Jewish people underwent much persecution. Non-persecuted religions, Christianity and Islam also do not have originals of anything. It is a problem. Documentary hypothesis was developed in Germany about 300 years ago in 1700-s.

@AlBerko R. Sherira is not in fact saying that these oral traditions were "works"; that's YDJ's inference (possibly correct, possibly not). So no anachronism there.

In the view of the discussion, it's good to note, that the production of the Mishnah was a 2-tiered process, as Rambam points in his "Introduction to Mishna". The same idea is developed further in the introduction to the Netziv's commentary Ha’amek Sh’alah to Sheiltos of Rav Hai Gaon (translated as "The Path of Torah"). Netziv notes that development of halachah is a 2-tiered process, which was performed by Sanhedrin. The process consisted of
1-st tier - legislation: issue of psak halacha to various life circumstances
2-nd tier - adjudication: combining of similar laws into a single halacha l'ma'aseh.
One can see an example of such a system not only in halacha but also in the 2nd perek of masechet Pirkei Avot with 5 students of Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakkai. There are 4 students who work hard arriving at an independent psak: Rabbi Eliezer ben Hyrcanus, Rabbi Joshua ben Hananiah, Rabbi Yose haKohein, and Rabbi Shimon ben Nethanel, and then comes the smartest of all Rabbi Eleazar ben Arach and makes the punchline. What is the purpose of the discussion in Avos? It is precisely to explain with simple examples how the 2-tiered process at arriving at halacha worked. R. Eleazar ben Arach did not work as a posek / legislator, he worked as an adjudicator, while the four other rabbis covered all the possibilities with their independent and diverse psak.
Such was development of the Mishnah. As evidence shows, the previous halachic work included mostly halachic commentary on Chumash and other books of Nach, which were available in some form and evidently edited later. Rabbi Yehuda haNassi's job was to produce a singular halachic work, which would unite approaches of other hachamim. He was a great adjudicator, while others produced psak to make the system work.
Mishnah was written in circumstances which radically differed from previous halachic work, when there was the Temple. Netziv explains that the holiness of the Temple somehow allowed to effortlessly arrive at the correct formulation, and no painful process of halachic argumentation was necessary. As a result, towards the end of the Temple, under Roman occupation, hachamim lacked the skill neccessary to make a correct psak. In Netziv's opinion, that's precisely what caused hesitation of R. Zecharia ben Avkulos regarding Bar Kamtza in Gittin 56a.
After the Temple destruction, a diverse legislative work was performed for several generations until a mature body of halacha emerged, and Mishna united these approaches at the end. In fact, many discussions in the gemara one can also view in exactly the same 2-tiered format as actually pointed out by sefer Havot Yair (see Talmud Reclaimed by R. Shmuel Phillips). Ravina and Rav Ashi were adjudicators of Gemara. R. Yosef Caro and R. Moshe Isserlish were adjudicators of Shulchan Aruch, etc.

Thank you, a rather fresh idea. I appreciate your knowledge and effort. So you're saying a rabbi in the 19th century suddenly gets a revealing understanding of the mechanisms of the compilation of the Mishna totally ignored by previous generations? Did you hear of the "confirmation bias"? The tendency to search for evidence that supports your claims while ignoring all others? Unfortunately, our tradition suffers enormously from it. You bring as evidence an ethical, rather than Halachic claim in Avos, where one rabbi prefers one student over the others.

But you overlook the real "Halachic" Mishnayos, where either one traditional opinion is listed or several rivaling ones without a conclusion. Adjudication is extremely rare in both Mishna and the Talmud, and the first attempts to distill the ruling Hahacha appeared in the times of the Geonim hundreds of years later.

You might want to move your answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60565/what-was-rabbi-yehuda-hanassis-role-in-compiling-the-mishnah it seems more appropriate there.

The whole question was about "the previous halachic work included mostly halachic commentary on Chumash and other books of Nach, which were available in some form and evidently edited later." What were they?

@AlBerko The 2-tiered system is also discussed by Rambam and Havos Yair by r. Yair Bacharach from 17th century. Not only by Netziv in the 19th. There were several factors which delayed Jewish understanding of the history. 1. Too much focus on kabalah, 2. too much focus on pilpul of Shulchan Aruch. Studies of Gemara became popular again only as a result of Vilna Gaon's revolution (see Arie Morgenstern book "The Gaon of Vilna and His Messianic Vision"). After Gaon, Netziv was the first who fully applied this method to a widest collection of available books.

@AlBerko As I already mentioned: Targum Yonatan ben Uziel, Mechilta of R. Yishmael, Mechilta of Shimon b. Yochai, Sifra, portions of Sifre, Seder Olam.

@AlBerko additional Targumim (Onkelos, Yerushalmi, etc.) also could have been produced.

Sefer "Kerem Yehoshua" by R.Yehoshua Cohen, p.157-159, when discussing arguments between Rashi and Tosafos, writes the following about the sources of R. Yehudah haNassi's learning:
Jerusalem Talmud, Shabbos 10:5 (63b) and Pesachim 10:1(68b) state that any law which R, Yehudah haNassi taught he learned from his mentor R. Yaakov ben Kodeshai (Korshai).
At first glance this seems strange, for in the Babylonian Talmud we find that R. Yehudah haNassi had many teachers:

His Father, Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel (Bava Metzia 84b)
R. Yehoshua ben Korcha (same place)
R. Meir (Eruvin 13b in Rashi, contrary to Jerusalem Talmud, Beitza 5:2 (20b); and see Tosafos Menachos 104a, s.v. מוריינא; Rashbam to Bava Metzia 51b, s.v. רברבי; and Maharshal and Rashash there)
R. Elazar ben Shamua (Eruvin 53a, and Menachos 18a)
R. Shimon [b. Yohai] (Shabbos 147b, Rashi to Beitza 26a, s.v. א"ל; Tosafos to Makkos 9b, s.v. נשמט; et. al.)
R. Yehudah [bar Ilai] (Shavuos 13a; and see Megilla 20a)
R. Yose [b. Halafta] (see Tosafos to Shabbos 51a, s.v. אילו)

(Note 7 sources in light with Nedarim 41a!)
However, nowhere in the Babylonian Talmud does it mention that he learned from R. Yaakov ben Kodeshai (Korshai)! So how can the Jerusalem Talmud say that any law he taught he must have heard it from R. Yaakov ben Kodeshai (Korshai), and not from any other teacher we listed?
The key to this puzzle can be found in Avodah Zarah 19a, which states in order to learn the logic and reasoning process of the Talmud (סברה) it is best to learn from several teachers, while in order to learn the text itself of the Talmud, as passed down by tradition, it is best to learn from one teacher, so as to avoid contradictions of wording. Likewise we find in Eruvin 53a: the Judeans studied from one rabbi and their Torah stayed with them permanently; the Galileans did not study from one rabbi, and their Torah did not stay with them permanently." Rashi explains (s.v. לא גמרי מחר רבה): "They [the Galileans] heard [the Gemara] from one rabbi i one wording and from another in a different wording. And even though both [rabbis] had the same thing, the change of wording confused them and made them forget."
Based on this we can explain as follows: The Jerusalem Talmud knew that all of R. Yehudah haNassi's teachers, listed above, only taught him logic and reasoning, after he had already learned the traditional text. But his principle rabbi, who taught him the text itself as passed down by tradition, was R. Yaakov ben Kodeshai (Korshai).
Btw. R. Yose b. Halafta wrote Midrash Seder Olam.

+1 Thank you. I think there's been some misunderstanding about my question and comments. Again, I didn't assume that Rabbi had no sources, I only wondered if there were any existing works, as finished and published books, besides the Tanach, that we already know was a pretty much finished work.
You keep saying that Rabbi studied from tons of different rabbis and I already agreed.

These Rabbis did formulate the texts or large portions of the texts (that I listed), from which R. Yehudah ha Nassi studied. He did not sit one on one with each of them as a student. R. Meir formulated mishnayot, R. Yehuda b. Ilai contributed to Sifre, R. Chiya to Tosefta and SIfra, R. Shimon to his Mechilta. R. Yishmael's Mechilta was complete too. Also, Peirush r. Yonatan ben Uziel was also already in existence.

We're going in circles. You seem not to differentiate between "teachings" and works. What R"M's Mishna a book in the Rabbi's library? Was R. Chiya's Tosefta? I understood that the tradition says that with the Mishna, Rabbi was given a special heavenly permit to issue a published work, not just "write sidenotes". So nobody before him compiled a finished work. IIRC the Mishna does not mention any other existing works.

Nope. In every generations rabbis kept notes of their decisions. The rabbis mentioned had their own compilations to date, which of course differed. Your answer mixes the process of making a halachic decision and adjudication, i.e. formulating a law based on many halachic decisions.

What's the evidence for your assumption that Rebbi physically received his rabbis' notes (assuming they themselves had any notes and didn't just learn everything by heart)?

Relying only on oral transmission causes too much forgetfulness.  There are a few gemaras about it. Also Rebbi did not study with r. Meir and r. Nathan haBavli, while both are mentioned as his teachers. R. Meir formulated majority of stam mishnayot. How can one explain that r. Yehuda took those verbatim without seeing the notes? He also had to incorporate in the language of the mishna all opinions side by side, while those did not follow the same logical structure. You question is legit. Why though do you ask it before trying to think yourself how writing of a Mishna could be done?

@YDJ It would be helpful if you tagged me so that I know that you're replying to me. That said, I have thought quite a bit on how the Mishna was written. My problem is with your answer. You made a lot of assumptions, but what is the basis for those assumptions? For example, how do you know that Rebbi didn't study with R"M and R"N? They were of his father's generation, after all.

@Harel13 Can we first agree that the Mishna was not "written by Rabbi" but more like "compiled and ascribed to him"? Rabbi was a political leader rather than "Gdol Hador" who had the authority to publicize such a work in writing.

@AlBerko, no, I very much disagree. Rebbi was a great talmid chacham and some of his own rulings appear in the Mishna. The Mishna is a compilation but it was also edited by him. No know-nothing "political leader" could have done something like that.

@Harel13 regarding R. Meir: there was a conflict between the Sages and he had to leave Eretz Israel. Eruvin 13b; Yerushalmi Beitzah 63a, r. Yehuda haNassi states that he only saw r. Meir from behind. R. Nathan took side of r. Meir in the conflict and had to go. Bava Batra 131a;  Yerushalmi Ketuvot 29a; Bava Batra 16a r. Yehuda haNassi makes a remark how he failed to treat r. Nathan properly as a youth. I agree that r. Yehuda haNassi was a great man as we learn in the last perek of Pirkei Avot. R. Sherira Gaon confirms that.

@YDJ the sources you brought show that Rebbi did indeed know R"M and R"N, and studied under them. That brings me back to my original question: Based on what do you believe that Rebbi had their personal notes?

@Harel13 you are rushing with comment. Those sorces state that Rebbi saw R. Meir and r. Nathan briefly once. Please check yourself. Stop this interrogation.

It's no interrogation. If you're going to present a claim, you should be ready to defend it. That's how things go in limud. I could break up the sources for you, but I see you're not interested. I'll leave.

@Harel13 i suggested sources. Have you already checked them to write your comment?

@YDJ I did, and as I said I could break them down for you and show why they don't mean what you think they mean. But I'm not sure whether you're interested in that.

I understood that Rabbi combined the two, but IIRC, he was never "Gdol Hador (in his generation) as in Rosh Hashana. What do you think about the claim that the Mishna was not "written by Rabbi" but more like "compiled and ascribed to him"? Did he come up with the idea of the 6 Sdarim and arrange the Mishnayos accordingly?

@Harel13 you may write your separate answer if you disagree. So far you are only writing critique without proofs.

@AlBerko i would be careful with the notion of Gadol haDor created by Hasam Soffer as applied to sages of Gemara. We have a mishna in the 6th perek of Pirkei Avot, which describes Rebbi as a great man. I think, it's a high standard to beat.

@YDJ I don't claim to know what Rebbi had in his library, hence my not posting an answer. I could have simply downvoted your answer without saying a word, but that's not my style.  Something to consider: How in the world could adult Rebbi with a son about to be wed have said that he only had Torah because he saw Rabbi Meir's neck one time in the middle of the night? Do you believe that until then Rebbi was an Am Ha'aretz? I think there's enough evidence from various sources that he was a talmid chacham long before, so clearly he wasn't referring to that single moment in the Yerushalmi.

Rebbi could have R. Meir's notes. He certainly could not study with R. Meir in his youth, when he had to learn with r. Yaakov ben Kodeshai (Korshai) as we learn from Yerushalmi, based on r. Cohen's explanation.

Don't let likes and dislikes affect your writing! Don't write for people to like you. Be true to yourself and your values.

Gdol Hador doesn't mean "a great rabbi" it means "the Greatest". So, if anything, his authority to "adjudicate" was political rather than "Toranic" - unlike his predecessors, he actually had the power to force his Psakim on other Rabbis and the general public.

@AlBerko what gain is there in a psak? Why would Rebbi need to enforce his psak? There is no end to speculation. The positions of the mishnah are quite balanced. Jewish halachic positions underwent two steps down in levels of stringency. The strictest positions were assumed by Saducees, who considered deoraisa even mitzvos from Nach. Then we had Beis Shamai who sought levels truth based on judgement in Shamaim.

Rebbi wrote a clear and relatively short order of exiting halacha, which any person could master. His formulations were accepted and loved. What exactly bothers you about mishna?
